# In VS 2005 How do I generate the connection strings for web.config?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005, web-config, connection-string

I thought that VS 2005 automatically generated the connection strings in the web.config, however I can't for the life of me remember how.

Comment: Automatically?  If I remember correctly (I am on VS.NET 2008) it only adds them for you when you utilize the designer to drag and drop a sql connection, or bind to a data source using the visual designer.

Comment: Yeah posted my own answer right before your comment showed up. Thanks anywho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah figured it out on my own. In the design view drag in the sql data source object and configure from there.

Comment: VS will add/update the connection string in the web.config whenever you use the wizards on a data-related control.